# Mlflow how to pass database username and password through config file or in secure way

Tags: bash, shell, mlflow

I have a script which start a mlflow server.

How to pass postgresql credentials in mlflow server in secure way.
When somebody start mlflow, they have to give username and password for backend-store-uri database.

e.g

```
mlflow server --backend-store-uri postgresql://psql_user_name:psql_password@localhost/mlflow_db --default-artifact-root s3://my-mlflow-bucket/ --host 0.0.0.0
```

How can we hide **psql_user_name:psql_password** or pass it in secure way to mlflow?
intention is to hide the username and password when somebody do grep for mlflow

Comment: isn’t there an option to pass the credentials from a file?

Comment: @Fravadona  , I did not able to get any such option ,that's what I am looking for

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any way to obfuscate your credentials with `mlflow` command, and even if there was, there are a few non-resolved bug reports about passwords being visible in the logs and through other means... So keep in mind that this DB's user/password could be leaked at any time and try to reduce its rights to the minimum

Comment: for example: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/1854 and https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/2832

Comment: appearing  in the logs file can be okay in my case but it should not visible in command line or when someone grep for mlflow process id.
Internally mlflow use python sql alchemy engine for db connection and for python flask application we can use conf file command line , cant we have something like that in mlflow

Comment: SQL Alchemy is used for this, and seems they are not supporting passwords outside of URIs, always mentioning about providing username and password in URI :(

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#add-parameters-to-the-url-query-string

Answer (score -1):

create a batch file for this command prompting for username and password

read -s -p "Enter Username: " user
read -s -p "Enter Password: " password
mlflow server --backend-store-uri postgresql://$user:$password@localhost/mlflow_db --default-artifact-root s3://my-mlflow-bucket/ --host 0.0.0.0

in this way, this command will not be logged in bash-history

Comment: This is useless - not only are the values just as visible to `ps` and similar, they are not even quoted, so they are subject to shell's word-splitting.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).